# Sqitch migration with ALTER SEQUENCE on Postgresql db has no effect

Tags: postgresql, sqitch

When I create a table with a Sqitch migration I want to initialize its starting `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY` with something other than `1`. However, for some reason the `ALTER SEQUENCE` command does not seem to have any effect.

My deploy migration looks something like this:

```
BEGIN;

  CREATE TABLE "user" (
    "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

    ... more columns ...
  );

  ALTER SEQUENCE "user_id_seq" RESTART WITH 12345;

COMMIT;
```

When the above migration has successfully run, the `id` column of first row I insert into my `user` table with have the value `1`.

However, if I execute the `ALTER SEQUENCE "user_id_seq" RESTART WITH 12345;` statement manually (after the migrations have run), the next row I insert, the `id` column has the value `12345`.

I have tried to move the `ALTER SEQUENCE...` statement into its own migration but this does not seem to have any positive effect.

How can I successfully execute the `ALTER SEQUENCE...` statement within a Sqitch migration?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```sql
SELECT setval("user_id_seq", 12345, false);
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html

UPDATED:

what about this? just tested it works fine

```
BEGIN;

CREATE SEQUENCE user_id_seq START 12345;

CREATE TABLE "user" (
  "id" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq'),
  --- rest fields
);

ALTER SEQUENCE user_id_seq OWNED BY user.id;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: I actually tried that, forgot to mention. Doesn't work either although it outputs the `SELECT` value when the migration runs.

Comment: Actually you case works too for me with one changing
`ALTER SEQUENCE test_user_id_seq RESTART WITH 12345;` I have removed singlequote.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It works me for too when I run the query directly on the db. But it doesn't work within the context of a Sqitch migration.

Comment: @Luke I assume you have mistake in your deploy file, because when I tested your case and my case both followed me to expected result, when `user.id` is `12345`. I mean testing with sqitch

Comment: OK. I think I found the issue. The migration and `ALTER TABLE...` as I have it in my question works fine. However, when I run my fixtures (dev data) and integration tests, I perform a `TRUNCATE` on the table to clear it out. I suspect that the `TRUNCATE` is resetting the `SEQUENCE` but I will never use `TRUNCATE` in prod anyway. So, this is just a local dev/test phenomenon. Thanks for your help!